# In logic circuit with one output , how to get all combination of input which produces a certain output ? (Without brute forcing)

Tags: python, bit, logical-operators, boolean-logic, circuit

Suppose i have a logic circuit , the logic circuit consist of input , static bit value (either 0 or 1) , and logic gate . All logic gate in the logic circuit takes two input and produce one output (for example , 1 AND 0 = 0). The logic circuit produces only one output (either 0 or 1).

The logic circuit only consist of three basic logic gate (NOT , OR ,AND).

How do i get all combination of input in the logic circuit which causes the logic circuit to produce a certain output ? For example , i want to get all combination of input which causes the logic circuit to produce an output of 1.

I know i can do this by brute forcing , trying every combination of input . But brute force method might be infeasible for large amount of input. So i wonder if i can do this without brute force method ?

I wrote some script implementation of logic circuit in python. But it is a wall of code (more than one hundred line) and probably not the best implementation of logic circuit in the world. So i don't find the need to post the code here . But if my code is needed , just tell me in comment and if i see enough demand then i will post it here.

Comment: what do you mean by large circuits? I think you have 2 options, try brute force or try to do some backward analisys. this last could be very hard, I don't know if you could leverange some existing libraries that could let you construct some pipeline to work

Comment: @UlisesBussi large circuit means the logic circuit contains a large amount of logic gate and input

Comment: You might look into logic programming systems as a place to start. How those are developed is a topic that books are literally written on -- it's far too broad for a Stack Overflow question to cover. But if you can model your logic in prolog or another system built for inductive logic, it can do the work of finding an optimal path to calculate inputs that satisfy your predicates.

Comment: I undertand what you mean by "large circuit" you mean high number of inputs and logical operations but, I want to know an aproximate order: 10 inputs? 100 inputs? 1e10 inputs?

Comment: If you've taken a formal computer science course, you might have studied Prolog or CLIPS; in the modern world we have core.logic and others -- but tool selection is itself explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: @UlisesBussi in my case i need 512 input , or maybe 1024 input . But i might need more than that , i don't think it is necessary to put here the amount of input i need.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i am in college , but i am on third semester, haven't learn about that or i forgot if such course exist in my college , or maybe it does exist but in different name , i don't know.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if you can explain how my question is too broad , i might able to edit the question to make it specific .

Comment: Typically logic programming is (or was, 20 years ago) covered somewhere around 3rd year, particularly for students on the AI track. That said -- logic programming is where people thought the future was in the early 80s; it's not _at all_ trendy today, even though the techniques are immensely useful in practice (my most recent startup experience is somewhere that had a successful exit after leveraging them heavily).

Comment: ...re: breadth, the problem effectively is that the tools that are best suited to solve this problem are taught over the course of a full semester. We can't teach them in a SO answer; there's just too much to cover.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ah , you right , it would takes long to explain it in SO answer. But however , i will keep the question because this is still a valid question and i honestly really don't know how to do it and maybe someone out there is kind enough to spare time to explain it to me and future reader of this question.

Comment: (btw, [Clojure's `core.logic`](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic) is the specific modern logic programming system I personally have the most experience with; http://minikanren.org/ is the foundation it's modeled off of, and the latter site has links to books/papers/etc).

Comment: SAT and/or SMT solvers are the usual tools for this type of job in my experience. SAT solvers routinely solve problem instances with millions of variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is best done with a SAT/SMT solver, like z3 from Microsoft: https://github.com/Z3Prover

It can be scripted from python, and you can ask it to find values of the inputs that give you the desired output. Here's a very simple example:

```py
from z3 import *

in1, in2 = Bools("in1 in2")
out = Bool("out")

s = Solver()

# Encode your circuit here. We'll just do out = in1 \/ in2
s.add(out == Or(in1, in2))

# require output to be true.
# You could also set it to False, if that's what you're looking for.
s.add(out == True)

print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

When I run this, I get:

```
sat
[in1 = True, in2 = False, out = True]
```

The first line says `sat`, which means the problem is indeed solvable. (Otherwise you'd get `unsat`.)

The second line is the assignment you should use to get this desired output. You can also program to enumerate all possible solutions, though of course that could lead to a very long running loop if there are many of them.

For details on how to code up your circuit so it's amenable to this sort of analysis, you should look up Tseytin Encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation

I should emphasize that if you're trying to "reverse-engineer" a one-way function (i.e., if your circuit is computing some sort of an encryption algorithm like AES/DES, or doing SHA-like hashing) all this will be futile. There's no SAT solver (or any other tool) that's in existence that can handle those kinds of problems. The kind of circuits I'm talking about here are regular functions, such as arithmetic, or other regular data-path. You've never indicated what sort of circuit you're dealing with, but keep that in mind.

Comment: I looked up the documentation , the library uses recursion . The logic circuit i am going to use is script generated , and are going to be very big . The library most likely will crash from stack overflow error. I could try blindly guessing the stack size that i need to prevent stack overflow , but the amount of logic circuit i create is script generated so i can't find a good way to guess the stack size.

Comment: SAT solvers are engineered to handle with very large inputs. I doubt it'll be a problem so long as you practice common good-coding style. Give it a try and see what you find. If size is really an issue, you can also use the so called DIMACS format, which z3 reads out-of-the box and is more compact: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/manuals/current/manual/index-seo.php/SATLINK____DIMACS